# isc-dhcp-server: control process exited with error code

Tags: networking, dhcp

I wrote [a script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ge8D.png) to start isc-dhcp-server.

[image]

But it [didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qfE2.png): "the control process exited with error code".

[image]

Plus,  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9tbj.png) is my configuration file of isc-dhcp-server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your second screenshot pretty clearly shows that a DHCP server is already running.  You can figure out what process ID the existing DHCP server is by running this command:

```
sudo netstat -planu | grep ':67\s'
```

<sup><sub>(Port 67 UDP is the [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server port.)</sub></sup>

Sample output:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ sudo netstat -planu | grep ':67\s'
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           5538/dnsmasq
```

In the example above, `5538` is the process ID of the existing DHCP server.  To get the service that is running the DHCP server with process ID `5538`, run this command:

```
sudo systemctl status 5538
```

<sup><sub>(Of course, you'd replace `5538` with the process ID that you found.)</sub></sup>

If the process wasn't started by a service, you can just kill it:

```
# SIGTERM (typically a graceful shutdown of the process)
sudo kill 5538

# SIGABRT (typically a more aggressive shutdown of the process)
sudo kill -6 5538

# SIGKILL (forcefully kill the process)
sudo kill -9 5538
```

If the process is part of a service, use `sudo systemd stop SERVICE.service` to stop the service, where `SERVICE` is the service name.  This should prevent the DHCP server from coming back up from the service's own monitoring.